# PHP find files on server which contain certain strings

Tags: php, arrays, function, output

I have a couple images in my images folder for example:

```
User12345_gallery0.png
User12345_profilePic.jpg
User12345_gallery1.png
User12345_gallery2.jpg
User54321_gallery0.png
```

What I'm trying to do is pass the user to my getimages.php and get that user's images.  I've never done this before so I'm struggling with the syntax.  Here's what I have so far:

```
if($_REQUEST['user']){
$ext = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg');
$dir = 'images/';
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$images = array();
foreach ($ext as $ex){
    if (file_exists(strpos($dir.$user."_gallery", "gallery"))) {
        //add file to $images???
    }
}
}
```

I want to check if the file contains the username and the instance of "gallery".  How can I do that?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: To begin with, `file_exists()` expects a file name and `strpos()` returns a string offset.

Comment: does your user id always have the same number of characters?

Comment: You could use [glob](http://www.php.net/glob) to do a pattern search. However, since it needs to scan all the filenames in the entire directory on each call, it will perform horribly if your site gets popular.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is wrong.  I don't know the exact file name...and I just noticed that I'm not looping through the entire images folder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `glob()` and `stripos()` for this..

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['user']){

    $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
    $images = array();
     foreach (glob("images/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
         if(stripos($filename,$user)!==false && stripos($filename,'gallery')!==false)
            $images[]=$filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the OP use `glob(array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'))`...?

Comment: Why not just use a pattern with glob? `glob($user."_gallery*")`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn looks like "_gallery" is not always part of the pattern, there is "profilePic" for example...

Comment: @webeno but OP wants only images that have gallery. `contains the username and the instance of "gallery"`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I thought it would be needed to find the `$user`... maybe best would be `glob($user."_gallery*.".array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'))` - would this work? looks like the OP wants to check for image extensions too...

Comment: You can't append an array to a string like that. You could use `glob($user."_gallery*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: The images extensions isn't crucial.  I just want the gallery images associated with that user to be found.

Comment: Sorry to turn your comments into a conversation :). I would just suggest that you use the `$user."_gallery*.{jpg, png, gif}"` pattern if searching for a specific user that you know idenified in `$user` and using `"*_gallery*.{jpg, png, gif}"` if searching for gallery for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just look at the pictures names in the directory and return the ones for your user ?

```
$ext = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg');
$dir = 'images/';
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];

// the length of your username (for the expression bellow)
$usernamelength  = strlen($user); 

// read a list of all files into an array
$filesindirarray = scandir($dir);

// loop through the list
foreach($filesindirarray as $filename)
{
   // does the filename start with
   if(substr($filename,0,($usernamelength+8)) ==  $user .'_gallery')
   {

      // fish out the files extension
      $fileext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      // if the extension of the files is in your list
      if(in_array($fileext,$ext))
         // add to images
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but in my question I showed that the way the images are named, some of them have "user_gallery..." and some have "user_profilePic...".  So I don't think your way would get back just the gallery pics

Comment: I changed the code sothat only pictures with _aggery in the name are returned.